# Kubernetes cert-manager certificate generating error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager

```
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age   From          Message
  ----     ------        ----  ----          -------
  Normal   Generated     30s   cert-manager  Generated new private key
  Normal   OrderCreated  30s   cert-manager  Created Order resource "letsencrypt-prod-2527702610"
  Warning  FailedOrder   27s   cert-manager  Order "letsencrypt-prod-2527702610" failed. Waiting 1h0m0s before retrying issuance.
```

i am trying change the email in cluster issuer i have already one generated with this certificate-manager in K8s Cluster.

Nginx ingress controller and cert-manager both running on cluster then why i am getting this error.

> Yesterday i tried for staging certificate and it's work but production
>   it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face a similar issue when I rapidly delete and then install my application using helm. You probably run into the following rate limit:

> We also have a Duplicate Certificate limit of 5 certificates per week.
>   A certificate is considered a duplicate of an earlier certificate if
>   they contain the exact same set of hostnames, ignoring capitalization
>   and ordering of hostnames. For instance, if you requested a
>   certificate for the names [www.example.com, example.com], you could
>   request four more certificates for [www.example.com, example.com]
>   during the week. If you changed the set of names by adding
>   [blog.example.com], you would be able to request additional
>   certificates.

[Source](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/)